# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to return a table with the depth of a node in a hierarchy represented using the nested set model, I'm following this tutorial but the query used in the section 'Finding the depth of Nodes' doesn't work for me: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

```
SELECT node.GroupName, (COUNT(parent.GroupName) - 1) AS depth
FROM CompanyGroup AS node,
        CompanyGroup AS parent
WHERE node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
GROUP BY node.GroupName
ORDER BY node.LeftID;
```

Running this query I get the error "*Column 'CompanyGroup.GroupName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*"

Can anyone explain why please?

Edit: wrong column in the error message, my apologies the error is: "*Column "CompanyGroup.LeftID" is invalid...*"

Comment: Have you searched this error?

Comment: Is this the exact query you are running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one -

```
SELECT 
      node.GroupName
    , depth = COUNT(parent.GroupName) - 1
FROM CompanyGroup node
JOIN CompanyGroup parent ON node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
GROUP BY node.GroupName
ORDER BY MIN(node.LeftID) --<--
```

Or try this -

```
SELECT 
      node.GroupName
    , depth = COUNT(parent.GroupName) - 1
FROM CompanyGroup node
JOIN CompanyGroup parent ON node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
GROUP BY node.GroupName, node.LeftID
ORDER BY node.LeftID
```

Comment: That works, thanks. Out of interest could you explain the problem?

Comment: @Jim Barton, when you use group by, each column in the select/order clause must be either defined via an aggregate function (like MAX, MIN, AVG, ...) or must be included in the group by clause.

Comment: of course, I couldn't get the solutions in the posts I found to work for me so I opened a new question

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a different query?  You should not be receiving that particular error, but rather something like `"Column "CompanyGroup.LeftID" is invalid in the ORDER BY..."`

This query should work:

```
SELECT node.GroupName, (COUNT(parent.GroupName) - 1) AS depth
FROM CompanyGroup AS node,
        CompanyGroup AS parent
WHERE node.LeftID BETWEEN parent.LeftID AND parent.RightID
GROUP BY node.GroupName
;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9fcbf2/2)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is the error you're receiving from the query you posted - are you sure you didn't mess it up?

Anyway, there's something else wrong here: you're using `node.LeftID` to order the results, but you can't od this. You should be receiving this message:

```
Column "node.LeftID" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Try removing ORDER BY and run it again.