# Cannot select most recent ticket from a collection of tickets

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of advanced ticket objects that has a structure like this:

```
AdvancedTicket
-Id
-BasicTicket
-CreatedDate

BasicTicket
-Id
```

And when I query my advanced ticket table I get this:

```
1, BasicTicketId1, 10/11/12
2, BasicTicketId2, 10/11/12
3, BasicTicketId1, 10/12/13

...
```

I want to be able to say "Give me all of the AdvancedTickets but only show me the most recent one for each advanced ticket".

I have this code that is not working:

```
from item in allAdvancedTickets
group item by item.BasicTicket.Id
into basicTicket
let d = basicTicket.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreatedDate)
orderby d descending
select basicTicket;
```

I am running into an error that says at least one item needs to implement iComparable.

I think this query is wrong to begin with but I have never used this function in linq before and I would appreciate some help.

Comment: What data type is item.BasicTicket.Id? There needs to be a comparer for that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should sort the items by `CreatedDate` first, group them, then select the first item in each group. That item would be the most recent one since you've already sorted them earlier.

That sequence would yield this query:

```
var query = from item in allAdvancedTickets
            orderby item.CreatedDate descending
            group item by item.BasicTicket.Id
            into basicTickets
            select basicTickets.First();
```

Per the comments, if you're using NHibernate there's a bug when it comes to grouping. You might be able to work-around it by using two queries in the following manner:

```
var idDateQuery = from item in _session.GetAllAdvacnedTickets()
                  orderby item.BasicTicket.Id, item.CreatedDate descending
                  select item;

var query = from item in _session.GetAllAdvacnedTickets()
            let top = idDateQuery.First(o => o.BasicTicket.Id == item.BasicTicket.Id)
            where item.Id == top.Id
            select item;
```

Note that I haven't tested this against NHibernate. You might need to drop to the SQL level instead if this work-around isn't possible.

Comment: That totally worked! This helps me so much and it makes sense why it was having trouble before :)

Comment: When I inline by call to get allAdvacnedTickets I get an error saying Column 'AdvancedTickets.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.. If I say _session.GetAllAdvacnedTickets.ToList() it works just fine.

Comment: @segFault what does `GetAllAdvancedTickets` do? That error typically relates to some SQL query that groups by one column and doesn't group or aggregate other columns that are being selected. Take a look at these two questions and read their answers and comments for more detail: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814343/), and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999817/).

Comment: its just _session.Query<AdvancedTickets>()

Comment: @segFault that's odd. Are you using NHibernate by any chance? If so, this appears to be a [bug in NHibernate](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3027) that has been around for awhile. It also appears to happen with HQL. You might need to drop to the SQL level for such queries. I do have a work-around idea, but I'm not testing against NHibernate, so you can try it out and see if it helps. The `ToList` approach works but it's not ideal since you're pulling all the records from the database down. I'll update my post shortly with the work-around idea.

Comment: Ok I am going to test it and I will let you know. Thanks for your help